# Can someone explain why these running times are right for this?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, runtime, big-o

An algorithm runs in time n^2 + 3n + 5 for all inputs of size greater or equal to 500 and in time 2^(2n) for all input sizes less than 500. Select all the true statements from below:

```
1: Its running time is O(2^(n))
2: Its running time is O(n^(2))
3: Its running time is Θ(n^(2))
4: Its running time is Θ(2^(2n))
5: Its running time is O(4^(n))
6: Its running time is Ω(n^(2))
```

the right answers are: 1, 2, 3, 5, 6

I have no idea how all of these can be answers to the problem above, please help!

Comment: Which ones do you have trouble with?

Comment: Well I want to know why they can all be running times of just one algorithm? @harold so I guess all of them

Comment: Do you understand the difference between O(...) and Θ(...)? If you do, then it seems like it should be obvious how more than one of these statements can be correct . . .

Comment: I guess I'm more confused on 5 and 1 as lower bounds for the algorithm @ruakh

Comment: @RyanFasching: By "lower bounds" do you mean "upper bounds"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that big-O notation only talks about the behavior of a function in the long term. Look back at the definition:

> f(n) = O(g(n)) if there are numbers n<sub>0</sub> and c such that **for any n ≥ n<sub>0</sub>**, we have f(n) ≤ c·g(n).

In the case of your function, your function behaves one way for "small" inputs and one way for "large" inputs. Big-O notation will only really consider the "large" case, so you can show that your function is O(n<sup>2</sup>), because for any n ≥ 500, we have

> f(n) = n<sup>2</sup> + 3n + 5 ≤ 5n<sup>2</sup>.

The definition of big-Ω works the same way - it only considers "sufficiently large" inputs, so you can say that your function is Ω(n<sup>2</sup>) because for any n ≥ 500, we have

> f(n) = n<sup>2</sup> + 3n + 5 ≥ n<sup>2</sup>.

So that means that your function is Θ(n<sup>2</sup>) as well.

So what about those other answers? Well, any function that's O(n<sup>2</sup>) is *also* O(4<sup>n</sup>) because big-O notation is an upper-bound, not a tight bound. It's not, however, Θ(4<sup>n</sup>), because the function isn't Ω(4<sup>n</sup>) since 4<sup>n</sup> grows dramatically faster than n<sup>2</sup> long term.